# What is this site that shows up as one of the top referrers to SO?

Tags: discussion, site-analytics

`dogshowsonice.com` is one of the top referrers of traffic for StackOverflow. Any idea what that is? The homepage is just a generic landing page. Google doesn't turn up anything interesting.

[image: dogshowsonice rankings]

Comment: it's most likely referrer spam

Comment: Dog shows on ice?  Dogs how so nice!

Comment: Dogs. How, son? Ice!

Comment: It's an Irishman's vanity page: Dogshow O'Nice

Comment: Dog shows *are* so nice.  Except when they check the sacks.  That's a bit creepy.

Comment: Sophos web protection reports this: "High Risk Website Blocked
Location: dogshowsonice.com
Access has been blocked as the threat Mal/HTMLGen-A has been found on this website.
Return to the page you were previously viewing."

Comment: Almost as entertaining as "Zoo Animals on Wheels" :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUK6rY7X1Gs

Comment: JeffreyBosboom.Comment.Add("Dog show, so nice!");

Comment: Who knew dogs like StackOverflow too ? It would explain some of the low quality questions though. woof:-)

Comment: @Jaco This very issue was addressed in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176641/what-do-the-dog-laptop-mean-in-the-stack-overflow-careers-advertisement

Comment: @kubi Maybe take out the plain text of `dogshowsonice.com`.  You are giving them exactly what they want.

Comment: Shouldn't the title and tag be 'referers'? (not enough rep to edit it myself)

Comment: @MiloPrice Yet another thing I learned today! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Answer (score 58):

Credit goes to @fuzzytree (I had no idea referrer spam was a thing)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spam

Comment: The things you learn...

Comment: talk about "you learn something every day"

Comment: Hmm... While this is interesting and I did learn something new, is this Meta post now serving their interests even more by providing more indexed links back to them?

Comment: @reirab there's no links to the site in question on this page. The domain is mentioned in text, but I don't believe this has much weight.

Comment: [The More You know★](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/the-more-you-know)...

Comment: Why can't people just do an honest days work like the rest of us..

Comment: @MsYvette Sometimes I wonder if it really pays off more than if they had invested the effort into something non-douchy.

Comment: @reirab, the site's name is wrapped by the `<code>` tag and not `<href>`. Also, most external links that have `<href>` receives a `rel="nofollow"` attribute by SE to prevent links to be indexed and to avoid spammers to benefit.